# Adding more labels to a chart's axis

Tags: asp.net

I'm making an ASP.NET where I'm using some charts. Currently one chart shows savings on the Y axis.
The chart is only showing 4 labels on the Y axis, in this case 0, 200, 400 and 600. How do I make so the chart shows more labels on one axis, say I want 0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the Axis's IntervalAutoMode from FixedCount to VariableCount did it.

```
<AxisY IntervalAutoMode="VariableCount">
</AxisY>
```